# How to assign role to newly created user

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am using `meteor-roles` packages and statically it creates the user admin@example.com, normal@example.com,.....
NOw I have a signup pages where the user can sign up.Initially I create the account by following code in client side, i am using coffeescritp:

```
  Accounts.createUser
    email: email
    password: password
```

By doing these I can create the new user. Now how do I assign the role to that newly created user. I have roles- admin, normal, manage-users.
When doing these

```
id = Meteor.userId()
roles = "admin"
Roles.addUsersToRoles id, roles
```

I get the error "`Exception while delivering result of invoking 'createUser' Error {} Error: Missing 'users' param`

How can I assign the role dynamically. 
Thank you in advance.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `Meteor.userId()` if the user ID you are assigning the role(s) too is the current user. You would need to call `Meteor.userLoginWith*()` before trying to use `Roles.addUsersToRoles(Meteor.userId(), roles)`.

I would suggest creating the user, assigning the roles, and then logging them in. If you log the user in prior to assigning an appropriate role, role-specific routes, allow functions, and publish functions may not behave properly.

I would suggest creating the user:

```
var userId = Accounts.createUser({
  username: 'username',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  password: 'passwordString',
  profile: {}
});
```

And then adding the user to the appropriate role:

```
var roles = ['admin', 'roleName']; 
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, roles);
```

Then finally logging them in, after the role(s) has been assigned.

Comment: ON doing above option i just get the following errors:
"Uncaught Error: Missing 'users' param "

Comment: This seems to work well for me. Are you doing this on the client or server? Try console logging the userId before you assign it to the role. Is it null?